# How to mock a function using Frisby and Jest to return custom response?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to mock a function using Frisby and Jest.
Here are some details about my code:

dependencies
axios: "^0.26.0",
dotenv: "^16.0.0",
express: "^4.17.2"

devDependencies
frisby: "^2.1.3",
jest: "^27.5.1"

When I mock using Jest, the correct response from API is returned, but I don't want it. I want to return a fake result like this: `{ a: 'b' }`.

How to solve it?

I have the following code:

```
// (API Fetch file) backend/api/fetchBtcCurrency.js
const axios = require('axios');

const URL = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json';

const getCurrency = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(URL);
  return response.data;
};

module.exports = {
  getCurrency,
};
```

```
// (Model using fetch file) backend/model/cryptoModel.js
const fetchBtcCurrency = require('../api/fetchBtcCurrency');

const getBtcCurrency = async () => {
  const responseFromApi = await fetchBtcCurrency.getCurrency();
  return responseFromApi;
};

module.exports = {
  getBtcCurrency,
};
```

```
// (My test file) /backend/__tests__/cryptoBtc.test.js
require("dotenv").config();
const frisby = require("frisby");
const URL = "http://localhost:4000/";

describe("Testing GET /api/crypto/btc", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock('../api/fetchBtcCurrency');
  });

  it('Verify if returns correct response with status code 200', async () => {
    const fetchBtcCurrency = require('../api/fetchBtcCurrency').getCurrency;
    
    fetchBtcCurrency.mockImplementation(() => (JSON.stringify({ a: 'b'})));

    const defaultExport = await fetchBtcCurrency();
    expect(defaultExport).toBe(JSON.stringify({ a: 'b'})); // This assert works

    await frisby
      .get(`${URL}api/crypto/btc`)
      .expect('status', 200)
      .expect('json', { a: 'b'}); // Integration test with Frisby does not work correctly.
  });
});
```

```
Response[
  {
    I hid the lines to save screen space.
  }
 ->>>>>>> does not contain provided JSON [ {"a":"b"} ]
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic lost reference problem.

Since you're using Frisby, by looking at your test, it seems you're starting the server in parallel, correct? You first start your server with, say `npm start`, then you run your test with `npm test`.

The problem with that is: by the time your test starts, your server is already running. Since you started your server with the real `fetchBtcCurrency.getCurrency`, jest can't do anything from this point on. Your server will continue to point towards the real module, not the mocked one.

Check this illustration: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heyset/a554f9fe4f34101430e1ec0d53f52fa3/raw/9556a9dbd767def0ac9dc2b54662b455cc4bd01d/illustration.svg

The reason the assertion on the import inside the test works is because that import is made after the mock replaces the real file.

You didn't share your `app` or `server` file, but if you are creating the server **and listening** on the same module, and those are "hanging on global" (i.e: being called from the body of the script, and not part of a function), you'll have to split them. You'll need a file that creates the server (appending any route/middleware/etc to it), and you'll need a separate file **just** to import that first one and start listening.

For example:

`app.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const { getCurrency } = require('./fetchBtcCurrency');

const app = express()

app.get('/api/crypto/btc', async (req, res) => {
  const currency = await getCurrency();

  res.status(200).json(currency);
});

module.exports = { app }
```

`server.js`

```js
const { app } = require('./app');

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('server is up on port 4000');
});
```

Then, on your *start* script, you run the `server` file. But, on your test, you import the `app` file. **You don't start the server in parallel.** You'll start and stop it as part of the test setup/teardown.
This will give jest the chance of replacing the real module with the mocked one before the server starts listening (at which point it loses control over it)

With that, your test could be:

`cryptoBtc.test.js`

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const frisby = require("frisby");
const URL = "http://localhost:4000/";
const fetchBtcCurrency = require('./fetchBtcCurrency');
const { app } = require('./app');

jest.mock('./fetchBtcCurrency')

describe("Testing GET /api/crypto/btc", () => {
  let server;

  beforeAll((done) => {
    server = app.listen(4000, () => {
      done();
    });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    server.close();
  });

  it('Verify if returns correct response with status code 200', async () => {
    fetchBtcCurrency.getCurrency.mockImplementation(() => ({ a: 'b' }));

    await frisby
      .get(`${URL}api/crypto/btc`)
      .expect('status', 200)
      .expect('json', { a: 'b'});
  });
});
```

Note that the order of imports don't matter. You can do the "mock" below the real import. Jest is smart enough to know that mocks should come first.

Comment: Also, please note that mocking the implementation as () => ({ a: 'b' }) is a bit naive, since that function is clearly an asynchronous function. If, in your code, you're using it inside an "async/await" flow, that's fine, but then you're testing implementation, and if somewhere in the future you change it to a promise-based approach, it's going to break, because the return has no "then".
You should always mock asynchronous functions with asynchronous functions as well, or with functions that return promises. Like: mockResolvedValue({ a: 'b' })

Comment: Thank you very much, bro Ina! Your explanation works perfectly for me!